# SSL enabled and all cookies added httpOnly Flag

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, ssl, cookies

I am using codeigniter and site is having SSl. On test environment it works perfect that all cookies are `HttpOnly` Except csrf cookie. 
With SSL protection it adds `HttpOnly` flag to csrf token too and not able to access using jquery.

All ajax request stops due to this.
Try to update codeigniter config file with following settings:

```
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

It adds `httpOnly` regardless of above settings.

Comment: Why is the ajax request stopped?

Comment: Because it cannot receive token from cookie

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you using? I ask because in the current version the CSRF cookie is definitely set using the config settings you show above. I am not sure how older version behave in this regard. Did you clear existing cookies from the browser after changing the config values and before reloading the page?

Comment: You really do not want to run with `$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE; $config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;` If your issue is needing to send the CSRF token/value to the server then extract it from the DOM instead of trying to read the cookie.

Comment: @DFriend I am using latest stable version 3.x,

Comment: Also I cant understand the last comment. My issue is related to grab cookie using javascript. I have multiple ajax request, hence i requires to use fetch from cooking using jquery. On my other server all cookies had httpOnly except csrf cookie, but here I have ssl and all cookies are having httpOnly flag so I cannot access it

Comment: I was saying that you should be using secure cookies and HttpOnly. If you do not it makes the site much more vulnerable to attack. Obviously, when using HttpOnly using javascript to read cookies is not possible. I was also suggesting using JQuery to obtain the CSRF key/value and pass that to the server in the ajax data. You do not provide any clue about any other cookies you need to read so it is impossible to comment on them.

Comment: That's true that need to have httpOnly, I wants all other cooking except CSRF token httpOnly. I have checked some other possible way to exclude httpOnly flag but not working

Comment: That's true that need to have httpOnly, I wants all other cooking except CSRF token httpOnly. I have checked some other possible way to exclude httpOnly flag but not working

Comment: Why not read the cookies from the server instead of on the client side?

Comment: That is the last hope, but wanted to have a way to make it accessible using javascript to avoid long waiting and user experience

Comment: Accessing cookies at the server adds no overhead. They are sent to the server by the browser automatically (depending on PHP settings) and  are accessible in the superglobal `$_COOKIE`.